# Decrements time in javascript

Tags: javascript

(second.innerHTML) -1 that worked but (num.innerHTML) -1 that not working why?

```
function doDcrements() {
     var hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
     var second = document.getElementById('second');  // the second is 20.
     var loopTimer = 0;
     if (second.innerHTML != "0") {
         second.innerHTML = (second.innerHTML) -1;
         second.style.color = "blue";
         loopTimer = setTimeout('doDecrements()',1000);
     }else {
         second.style.color = "grey"; 
         hidden.style.display = "block";   
     }
 }
```

.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
function doDcrements() {
         var hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
         var second = document.getElementById('second'); // the second is 20. 
         var loopTimer = 0; 
         var num = document.getElementById('num'); // the number is 20. 
         if (second.innerHTML != "0") {
             second.innerHTML = (num.innerHTML) -1;
             second.style.color = "blue";
             loopTimer = setTimeout('doDecrements()',1000);
         }else {
             second.style.color = "grey";  
             hidden.style.display = "block";   
         }
     }
```

when I create it by for loop it not happens :

```
function doDcrements() {
    var hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
    var second = document.getElementById('second');
    for (i=20; i<=0; i--) {
           if (second.innerHTML != "0") {
             second.innerHTML = i;
             second.style.color = "blue";
             loopTimer = setTimeout('doDecrements()',1000);
         }else {
             second.style.color = "grey";  
             hidden.style.display = "block";   
         }
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="hidden">started</div>
<p id="second">20</p>
<div onClick="doDcrements();">Download</div>
```

Comment: It is preferred to do `setTimeout(doDecrements, 1000);` instead of `setTimeout('doDecrements()',1000);`

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(second.innerHTML) -1 that worked but (num.innerHTML) -1 that not working why?`

Without seeing your code, the only guess is that num.innerHTML is not giving you a string that is convertible to number. Examples:

`'20' - 1 = 20`

`'<input name="xyz" val="20"/>' - 1 = NaN`

Your HTML does't have any element with id="num". If this is the case, num will be null.

Changes
`setTimeout(doDecrements,1000);

    for (i=20; i >=0; i--)`

Answer (score 2):

Please look at your for loop:

```
for (i=20; i<=0; i--)
```

i=20 and i<=0. It will never run.

Comment: ACK, they probably meant it vice-versa (`>=` instead of `<=`).